# Get available databases name in sql server 2014

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I want to get the names of all available databases in SQL Server 2014

My code for this is not working:

```
import java.sql.*;


public class TestSql {
     public  static void main (String[] args){
         String connnectionURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\FAISAL-FAS:1433;";

         try {
         Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
         Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connnectionURL);
         ResultSet rs = conn.getMetaData().getSchemas();

         while(rs.next()) {

            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }

         }
         catch(Exception e){}

     }
}
```

Comment: Please describe what "not working" means? Does it compile and run, but not produce the desired result? Or does attempting to compile it bring down your entire network? Or somewhere between?

Comment: How about "select * from sys.databases"

Comment: Maybe you need to use `DatabaseMetaData.getCatalogs()` instead.

Comment: @alroc it compile and run but dont give me the results

Comment: @MarkRotteveel DatabaseMetaData.getCatalogs() also not give me compile run but no result shown

Comment: Then you are using an old JDBC driver. The current Microsoft driver **does** return all databases when calling `getCatalogs()`

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774 
enu\sqljdbc_6.0.8112.100_enu.exe    I am using this dirver and in this package jre 8 \sqljdbc42 this is the latest driver i found

Answer (score 0):

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1860/identify-when-a-sql-server-database-was-restored-the-source-and-backup-date/

Try this, some additional information will also be fetched.